# Find The Most Repeated Value In a Field using Hive or Pig

Tags: hive, apache-pig, bigdata

How to find the most repeated value in a field using Hive or Pig ?
Database values are in the following format

```
cricket,Football,Basketball,Volleyball 
cricket,Football,Basketball
Running cricket,Football
Basketball,Volleyball Football,Basketball,Volleyball,Baseball,Cycling
Running Shooting,Football,Running
```

I want to find the most common games from the list.

Comment: What should be the output in this case?Is it for each row or the entire dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Do a word count on the data and then get the word with the max count.

```
lines = LOAD 'test4.txt' as (line:chararray);
sports = FOREACH lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as sport;
groupedsport = GROUP sports BY sport;
sportcount = FOREACH groupedsport GENERATE group as sport, COUNT(sports) as total;
groupedsportcount = GROUP sportcount ALL;
maxvalue = FOREACH groupedsportcount  GENERATE MAX(sportcount.total);
maxsportcount = FILTER sportcount BY (total == maxvalue.$0);
DUMP maxsportcount;
```

The above can be achieved by sorting the counts in desc order and limiting the output to 1.However, if there are multiple max counts this would not return all words with max count.

```
lines = LOAD 'test4.txt' as (line:chararray);
sports = FOREACH lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as sport;
groupedsport = GROUP sports BY sport;
sportcount = FOREACH groupedsport GENERATE group as sport, COUNT(sports) as total;
orderedsportcount = ORDER sportcount BY total DESC;
maxsportcount= LIMIT orderedsportcount 1;
DUMP maxsportcount;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your text in the file m.txt and done the following operation to get the desired output.

```
str = load '/home/abhijit/Downloads/m.txt' AS (str:chararray);
```

We will use `TOKENIZE` function to split a string of words (all words in a single tuple) into a bag of words (each word in a single tuple).

```
tokens = foreach str generate TOKENIZE(str);

dump tokens;
```

The output is in the form of bag.

```
({(cricket),(Football),(Basketball),(Volleyball)})
({(cricket),(Football),(Basketball)})
({(Running),(cricket),(Football)})
({(Basketball),(Volleyball),(Football),(Basketball),(Volleyball),(Baseball),(Cycling)})
({(Running),(Shooting),(Football),(Running)})
```

`FLATTEN` :  It un-nests tuples as well as bags. For tuples, flatten substitutes the fields of a tuple in place of the tuple.
When we un-nest a bag, we create new tuples.

```
tokens = foreach str generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(str));

dump tokens;

(cricket)
(Football)
(Basketball)
(Volleyball)
(cricket)
(Football)
(Basketball)
(Running)
(cricket)
(Football)
(Basketball)
(Volleyball)
(Football)
(Basketball)
(Volleyball)
(Baseball)
(Cycling)
(Running)
(Shooting)
(Football)
(Running)
```

Here to get more accuracy you can try and get the string/words in one case so you will get a good result and proper count. So convert them in lowercase using `LOWER`

You can also convert it to Uppercase using `UPPER`

```
tokens = foreach str generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(LOWER(str)));
```

the output will be :

```
(cricket)
(football)
(basketball)
(volleyball)
(cricket)
(football)
(basketball)
(running)
(cricket)
(football)
(basketball)
(volleyball)
(football)
(basketball)
(volleyball)
(baseball)
(cycling)
(running)
(shooting)
(football)
(running)
```

`Group` : Groups the data in one or more relations.

```
grps = group tokens by $0; 
dump grps;
```

Here group creates 2 fields, one at `$0`  and other at `$1`.
`$0` indicated the key and `S1` is the group of tuples that have th same group key(i.e `$0` : key field).

The output shows the fields grouped by a key :

```
(Cycling,{(Cycling)})
(Running,{(Running),(Running),(Running)})
(cricket,{(cricket),(cricket),(cricket)})
(Baseball,{(Baseball)})
(Football,{(Football),(Football),(Football),(Football),(Football)})
(Shooting,{(Shooting)})
(Basketball,{(Basketball),(Basketball),(Basketball),(Basketball)})
(Volleyball,{(Volleyball),(Volleyball),(Volleyball)})
```

`COUNT` function counts the number of `tuples($1)` for a `key field($0)`.

```
cnt = foreach grps generate $0, COUNT($1);
dump cnt;
```

The output shows the counts for the words:

```
(Cycling,1)
(Running,3)
(cricket,3)
(Baseball,1)
(Football,5)
(Shooting,1)
(Basketball,4)
(Volleyball,3)
```

`ORDER` is used to order the tuples in descending order. So will get the highest one at the top.

```
ord = order cnt by $1 desc;
dump ord;
```

The output after the ordering :

```
(Football,5)
(Basketball,4)
(Running,3)
(cricket,3)
(Volleyball,3)
(Cycling,1)
(Baseball,1)
(Shooting,1)
```

`Limit` : It restricts the number of output tuples to the specified count.

```
maxWord = limit ord 1;
dump maxWord;
```

The final output is

```
(Football,5)
```

Comment: This will not give the correct answer if there is another tuple with the same max count.Say (cricket,5)